# One or more project was not loaded properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

After copying the project to another laptop/ PC, when I want to open the solution, VS2010 shows the error "One or more project was not loaded properly". I have tried running visual studio in admin mode but that did not solve the problem.

Comment: Are you sure that you copied all the projects referenced from the solution? Open the .sln file in notepad and check what paths are used to reference the projects.

Comment: yes i have copied everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe because the project from where you copied was configured with IIS configurations and you are trying to run the project in visual studio's default environment.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually a result of an inconsistency in your solution or projects. Open the solution file in an external editor (such as notepad) and check that the path it has to the projects is available and did not change. There shouldn't be any absolute paths in the solution file.

Answer (score 0):

you have to right click on your project and set as a start up project after that you have run your project,
I seem to have found unloaded project, after noticing there's one missing by manually counting and comparing it to the number of projects the solution explorer reported. It was deep inside another folder in the solution explorer that I never used and assumed that had nothing worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

It's a familiar issue. Looks like the project you are trying to open was created in higher version than what you have. If the project is in MVC, make sure you have installed MVC OR Make sure you have appropriate version of .NET installed in your system. 
I work with NopCommerce and a couple of times I downloaded new version and got same error message. It goes away once I install the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Because you tagged it `ASP.NET` make sure you have all the `ASP.NET` components installed. Those are not part of .net framework but might be necessary in your project.